# How do I format a retweet request through the Abraham twitteroauth php class?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm damned if I can make this work. Your help would be appreciated. I have valid access tokens, and can use twitteroauth to post status updates. However: every way I've tried to come at retweets has failed.

```
$parameters = array('id' => $status_id);
$retweet = $connection->post('statuses/retweet', $parameters);
```

Gets an error response of "not found." I'm not sure what's not found - the id of the tweet that I'm trying to retweet, or the method I'm calling (statuses/retweet). I'm passing valid ID's through the request (I can find them on Twitter), and so on. Any ideas?

Here's the documentation:
http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/retweet/:id

I've also tried:

```
$parameters = array('id' => $status_id);
$retweet = $connection->post('statuses/retweet/', $parameters);

$parameters = array('id' => $status_id);
$retweet = $connection->post('statuses/retweet/:', $parameters);
```

and...

```
$retweet = $connection->post('statuses/retweet/:123456.json');
```

With either null responses (??) or the same enigmatic "not found."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$retweet = $connection->post('statuses/retweet/123456');
```

`:id` is a variable syntax that similar to PHP's `$id` so you replace it in its entirety with the value.

`$parameters` is only used when the key value pairs are getting added as URL parameters like `?key=value` not in the URL path.

The format is automatically handled by the library so you should not include `.json` manually.

Comment: Whew - got it working! Thank-you so much for your help - its super appreciated. You can see it in action here: http://politics.rodedwards.ca/list/posts  Implementation isn't complete yet, but much closer now. Cheers!

Comment: can you help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275383/how-to-retweet-using-php-twitter-api

Answer (score 2):

Another tip on this issue is to reference "id_str" rather than the "id" as the "id" integer is sometimes wrong.

Comment: The `id` parameter isn't wrong, some languages can't handle numbers that large and round it.