# How to retweet using PHP Twitter API?

Tags: php, twitter

HI I have searched over the internet for some example how to retweet, but with no success. If you go to [the demo](http://test.attila-naghi.com/manage_tweets.php), you will see that I got a lot of tweets from a specific account, but now I have no idea how to retweet by pressing the button "retweet". I am using [tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth). So I have no clue where to start. Can you help me with this? I started to learn about Twitter API and PHP just yesterday.

I tried something like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
require 'tmhOAuth.php'; 
$connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'user_token' => "3256207803-x4dhnsmpZ5cW8lJvYYBs512hRr1pCOFhbow2OSg",
    'user_secret' => "1VQtokXnkiMdOsmdNPkGJ6v1kygM1nvTWdPoiXXgZHOiP",
    'consumer_key' => "EeDo2GFRy7aQws0xNfIWOYlnk",
    'consumer_secret' => "CDhD7YXsAGniDNiFbpjsn8kkq33nsg8Nt5REetgjaXJ7SGuwO7"
));

$parameters = array();
if (isset($_GET['t_id'])){
    $parameters['id'] = $_GET['t_id'];
    $twitter_path = '1.1/statuses/retweet.json';
    $http_code = $connection->request('POST', $connection->url($twitter_path), $parameters );
    var_dump($http_code);
}
```

The content of the class is on Github.

Comment: any idea it is welcomed

Comment: @KevinSunny I tried smth , but no result :( this give me 404 the var_dump

Comment: Make sure you reset your application secret if you posted the real on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
$twitter_path = '1.1/statuses/retweet.json';
```

doesn't exist, you can use :

```
$twitter_path = '1.1/statuses/retweet/' . $_GET['t_id'] . '.json';
```

But, without parameters in your request

```
$http_code = $connection->request('POST', $connection->url($twitter_path));
```

[Link to the official documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/retweet/%3Aid)